# Simplest way to read an csv file using php

Tags: php

What would be the most simple way to read a csv file using php

Here is the code, the problem here is, it reads everything in one line

```
$row = 1;
if (($handle = fopen("1.csv", "r")) !== FALSE) {
    while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
        $num = count($data);
        echo "<p> $num fields in line $row: <br /></p>\n";
        $row++;
        for ($c=0; $c < $num; $c++) {
            echo $data[$c] . "<br />\n";
        }
    }
    fclose($handle);
}
```

Thanks
Jean

[edit]

Apologies, yes I want to read a csv file

Comment: Guys, I am not looking for a PHP class, just a simple script that can read an excel file.

Comment: Note that a CSV file is NOT an Excel file

Comment: @mark baker yes a csv file, changed the title...thanks

Comment: Are you running this script on a Mac? or against a CSV file generated on a Mac? If so, there's a special Note about line endings on the fgetcsv() page of the PHP manual

Comment: @X10nD , if an answer solves your problem, please, mark it as correct. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

**Edit:**
Seems to me that you want to read CSV files.

[image]

Here is an **functional example** for the spreadsheet above:

> $file_handle = fopen("widgets.csv",
> "r");
>
> while (!feof($file_handle) ) {
>
> $line_of_text = fgetcsv($file_handle,
> 1024);
>
> print $line_of_text[0] .
> $line_of_text[1]. $line_of_text[2] .
> "<BR>";
>
> }
>
> fclose($file_handle);

But if you **really want to read files in Excel format. xlsx**, you can use the PHPExcel library.
http://phpexcel.codeplex.com/

**Reading a spreadsheet**:

> $objReader = new PHPExcel_Reader_Excel2007();
>
> $objPHPExcel = $objReader->load("05featuredemo.xlsx");

**Set properties**

> echo date('H:i:s') . " Set
> properties\n";
>
> $objPHPExcel->getProperties()->setCreator("Maarten Balliauw");
>
> $objPHPExcel->getProperties()->setLastModifiedBy("Maarten
> Balliauw");
>
> $objPHPExcel->getProperties()->setTitle("Office
> 2007 XLSX Test Document");
>
> $objPHPExcel->getProperties()->setSubject("Office
> 2007 XLSX Test Document");
>
> $objPHPExcel->getProperties()->setDescription("Test document for Office 2007 XLSX,
> generated using PHP classes.");

**Add some data**

> echo date('H:i:s') . " Add some
> data\n";
>
> $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0);
>
> $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('A1', 'Hello');
>
> $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('B2', 'world!');
>
> $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('C1', 'Hello');
>
> $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('D2', 'world!');

**Rename sheet**

> echo date('H:i:s') . " Rename
> sheet\n";
>
> $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setTitle('Simple');

**Save Excel 2007 file**

> echo date('H:i:s') . " Write to
> Excel2007 format\n";
>
> $objWriter = new
> PHPExcel_Writer_Excel2007($objPHPExcel);
>
> $objWriter->save(str_replace('.php',
> '.xlsx', **FILE**));

**Read specific sheets only**

You can set the option setLoadSheetsOnly on the reader, to instruct the reader to only load the sheets with a given name:

> $objReader = new
> PHPExcel_Reader_Excel2007();
>
> $objReader->setLoadSheetsOnly(
> array("Sheet 1", "My special sheet")
> );
>
> $objPHPExcel =
> $objReader->load("05featuredemo.xlsx");

That's it!

More info and docs in:

http://phpexcel.codeplex.com/

Comment: // You can create new spreadsheets as well.
$objPHPExcel = new PHPExcel();

Answer (score 1):

You might try removing the 'length' parameter, or setting to 0, especially if you have a line longer than 1000 characters.

Answer (score 0):

If you use php under windows you can create a com object.

> $excel_app = new
>   COM("Excel.application") or Die ("Did
>   not connect");

Answer (score 0):

Try [PHP-ExcelReader](http://sourceforge.net/projects/phpexcelreader/). I never used it but it claims to be cross platform.

Answer (score 0):

You don't indicate which version of Excel; but take a look at [PHPExcel](http://www.phpexcel.net) (which can read BIFF5-8 formats, and the rare Excel2003 XML format, as well as the more recent OpenXML standard introduced with Excel2007). It's pure PHP, so will run on any platform (no need for .COM).

declaration of vested interest: I am one of the developers.

Comment: I am trying to write the script myself, rather than use one thats available, its helpful in debugging.  Looking for something thats universal

Comment: If you seriously want to write a script to read Excel files all by yourself, then good luck to you... it's a **lot** of hard work (PHPExcel has been 3 1/2+ years in development, and is still ongoing) especially if you're starting with a CSV reader that simply requires PHP's built-in functions. But if you really want to embark on writing an Excel reader, why not help an existing project that's available to the whole PHP developer community rather than simply write it for yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Following is the best working example:

```
<?php

ini_set('auto_detect_line_endings', TRUE);

$header = '';
$rows = array_map('str_getcsv', file('ZE5C630852D4DB9AD75E5DE.csv'));
$header = array_shift($rows);
$csv = array();
foreach ($rows as $row) {
  $csv[] =  $row;
}

/*echo "<pre>";
print_r($csv);*/

?>
```