# convert excel cell containing json into csv

Tags: php, json, excel, csv

I have a series of test cases in xlsx format that I need to convert into a csv file, however some of the rows have snippets of json mixed in with straight text and they also have line breaks (/n) (returns) within the cell. This is making conversion to csv a nightmare. I am trying to convert my test cases into csv in order to import them into the Test Rail application (which is suggesting a php script, but the script won't work since the csv fails to delimit cells with the json content, etc) please help!

script expects : title, type, priority, step, result

row 1 of data in xlxs file (office 2011 for mac) contains : 
title : test 1, 
type: some test type in text ie 'regression'
priority: some text ie 'high',
step :
Create an enabled Profile with only a Base Visit history rule.
Ie: json body :

```
{
  "name": " Basic Rule Only",
  "description": ""a basic rule only"
  } 
}
```

result: contains some text with ctrl+alt+option btwn sentences like : 
Verify 400 Bad Request is returned with similar error msg 'The request content was malformed:
key not found: name.'

Comment: Have you got the solution?

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet is to write a script to get the data out of the xlxs file directly.  xlsx files are just a standard zip file with an XML file inside containing the data and some other files containing the styling.  Your language of choice probably already has a XLSX parser you can just use.

If you want to stick with the CSV route Excel 2013 appears to export newlines within CSV fields at \n and uses \r\n for end of record so you might be able to use that to tell the difference between a new line embedded in a field and the end of a record depending on how you are parsing the CSV file ie: using a library that doesn't support that nuance then reading the xlsx directly might still be easier.

Answer (score 0):

If you go into Excel and File / Save As then select CSV, even cells with CR/LF in them as well as embedded quotes will save properly according to CSV conventions.  Specifically:

- Any cell with a comma or CR/LF will be quoted
- Any quote within a quoted cell will be saved as two quotes ("")

Just tested this.

Any application that can read files according to the CSV spec should be able to read a properly quoted and escaped CSV.

Answer (score 0):

As @Erik-j suggests if you export the dataset from Excel into the csv format then any csv-compliant application should be able to read it. If Excel can read back csv exported by Excel then the data set is ok and you have an incompatible reader.

The problem with csv is that the format is quite vague (e.g. delimiters differ) and the only valid reference specification is the Excel itself. (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values#Toward_standardization).

If you can not use another more strictly defined interchange data format (e.g. xml based) then take the php script suggested by Test Rail (you're probably refering to this one - http://docs.gurock.com/testrail-admin/migration-csv) and fix it.

This [Simplest way to read an csv file using php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3960772/simplest-way-to-read-an-csv-file-using-php) StackOverflow answer should guide you

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that it was because I was using Mac version of Excel which uses \r for end of line instead of what my script expected (\n or \r\n). I used Sublime Text to convert to \n and my script parsed the csv into my array as expected. I wouldn't have come to this conclusion without all of your helpful suggestions so thank you for your responses!